# How to call wcf using Reflection and app.config?

Tags: c#, wcf, reflection, app-config

I create a class library project[MyLibrary] in vs2010 and add Service Reference[http://127.0.0.1/MyService.svc].so it includes such node in app.config.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://127.0.0.1/MyService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService"
            contract="MyService.IMyService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I compile MyLibrary project ,it generate MyLibrary.dll and MyLibrary.dll.config.
Generally，I can call wcf method such as:

```
MyService.MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient();
```

int result = client.Add(3,6);

I haven't operate app.config through programe.it works well.

Now,I write another programe to load MyLibrary.dll and call wcf method using refelection.it generate error:
Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'MyService.IMyService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

I think it hasn't read the Configuration in app.config using reflection at runtime.I try to use such method,it still does not work.

```
string assemblyPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
string configPath = assemblyPath + ".config";
currentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", configPath);
typeof(ConfigurationManager)
    .GetField("s_initState", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
    .SetValue(null, 0);

typeof(ConfigurationManager)
    .GetField("s_configSystem", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
    .SetValue(null, null);

typeof(ConfigurationManager)
    .Assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(x => x.FullName == "System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths").First()
    .GetField("s_current", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
    .SetValue(null, null);
```

If I don't want to change calling wcf code above, What can I do? How to let programe to load and recognize app.config using reflection at runtime. Seems useless reflection as.Thanks!

Comment: In your "new program", what is in your app.config?

Comment: Nothing,MyLibrary refenrence wcf,so   wcf client configuration exists in Mylibrary.dll.config.At runtime,when call wcf method,how to find automatically the wcf configuration in Mylibrary.dll.config。I still use such code:MyService.MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient();

Comment: if I haven't change the way of calling,such error:Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'MyService.IMyService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section.so,I think it can't get the wcf configuration in Mylibrary.dll.config using reflection.

Comment: if use reflection,how to init and load Mylibrary.dll.config。
moreover，when call wcf method,it find automatically the wcf configuration in Mylibrary.dll.config。if not use reflection ,why it know the app.config and use the wcf configuration?

Comment: It has nothing to do with calling via reflection.  There error message is indicating that the configuration in Mylibrary.dll.config cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

You should copy `<system.servicemodel>` section from MyLibrary.dll.config to app.config of your application references MyLibrary.dll. It should be enough. Anyway, you are asking how to load app.config. In this [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2007/10/19/loading-the-wcf-configuration-from-different-files-on-the-client-side.aspx) described how to load WCF client configuration from any file. But again, it should be enough to copy servicemodel section.

Comment: Thanks,I can't copy <system.servicemodel> section from MyLibrary.dll.config to app.config.I can't operate the app.config,The MyLibrary.dll is called by Quarz.net.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with calling via reflection.  There error message is indicating that the configuration in `Mylibrary.dll.config` cannot be found.  You would get the same error if you were calling the client code directly referencing Mylibrary.dll without the configuration added to the new program's app.config (or web.config).

```
MyService.MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient();
```

By default, the above code will look in the currently running process's config file and look for `<system.servicemodel>`.  Your new program's configuration needs the information in the Mylibrary.dll.config file to be added to it's configuration file.  Otherwise, you must configure the client in code directly.